# Error while installing python-snappy on ubuntu with python3.11 version, fatal error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, python-3.11

I am facing below error while installing python-snappy on ubuntu. I am using python-snappy==0.6.1 version. **This package worked with python3.8 however I am seeing issue with python3.11 version.**

```
Running setup.py install for python-snappy: started
Running setup.py install for python-snappy: finished with status 'error'
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.11.0/include -I/opt/python/3.11.0/include/python3.11 -c src/snappy/snappymodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/snappy/snappymodule.o
      src/snappy/snappymodule.cc:33:10: fatal error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory
         33 | #include <snappy-c.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-snappy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for python-snappy did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

Can you please assist me to get rid of this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I also have the same issue. Looks like some file renaming

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Py3.11 incompatible. Py3.10 might work.